# How to return a list of FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API (ASP.NET Core 2.2) service where I need to loop through a list of OIDs and return a decoded byte[] encoded into a FileStreamResult via a MemoryStream. If I remove the OIDs from the list and only run it once I can return the FileStreamResult as a PDF document. I need to be able to return the same FileStreamResult with each OID being passed into the MemoryStream but I am only getting a text result returned:

```
[
    {
        "fileStream": {
            "canRead": true,
            "canSeek": true,
            "canWrite": true,
            "capacity": 300009,
            "length": 300009,
            "position": 0,
            "canTimeout": false
```

The method call on the Controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchValue)
{
     var oid = await _oidLookup.LookupOid(searchValue);
     byte[] documentBytes = await _extractDocument.ExtractDocument(oid.FirstOrDefault());

     if (documentBytes != null)
     {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
      }

      return Ok("No documents found");
}
```

But when I change it to:

```
if (oidList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var oid in oidList)
    {
        byte[] documentBytes = await _extractDocument.ExtractDocument(oid);

        if (documentBytes != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
            fileStreamResults.Add(new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf"));
        }

        return fileStreamResults;
    }
}
```

I get the text result listed above.

If I loop through the list of OIDs like this:

```
foreach (var oid in oids)
{
    byte[] documentBytes = await _extractDocument.ExtractDocument(oid);

    if (documentBytes != null)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(documentBytes);
        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

I only get the first document.

I need to be able to loop through a list of OIDs and return each of the FileStreamResult as multiple PDF documents.

Comment: You can only return 1 task per controller method.  The loop should be in the calling method?  Javascript to loop ajax calls to the method maybe?  You may need to open multiple tabs to do this.... not real sure.

Answer (score 3):

First, any method, action or not cannot have multiple return statements. As it stands, the method will simply return in the first iteration of the loop and that's it - no further enumerations will occur. That is of course why you're only getting the first item.

It *is* possible to do a `yield return`, which is probably what you were trying to achieve here. For example:

```
yield return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
```

Which would then require a return type of the method of `IEnumerable<FileStreamResult>`. However, that won't actually work here, because you can only return one `IActionResult`, not an enumerable of `IActionResult`s.

One request = one response. A file is a full response. You cannot return multiple files in a single request. Full Stop. It's simply not how things work. If you need to return multiple files in a single request, your only option is to return an *archive* of those files (i.e. a zip file). That way you're still returning just one file; it just happens to be an archive that contains multiple files. That's your only choice, though.